# Can a one to many relationship in rails create a parent object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

If I have an `category` class that has many `products` and each product would only have one category so that my models looked like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :category
end
```

and this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

Then, from the `belongs_to` side of products, can I create a category_name in my Product Model using: `create_category`? How can I tell what auto-generated methods are available to me on the product side of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tell what auto-generated methods are available to me on the product side of things?

By reading the corresponding documentation on [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) (i.e. [has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) and [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)). It tells you what methods are added.

In your case, you get `my_product.create_category` and `my_category.products.create` along many other methods.

Comment: ah! so its available on the instance not on the class - correct?

Comment: Yes. These methods are only useful on a specific instance. If you want to create a `Category` not related to a `Product`, you just use `Category.create`.

Answer (score 0):

you can used nested forms to create a category when a category doesn't exist or choose one if it already does exist within the new product create form.

This video from railscast should help

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Sure I know this - What I am looking for is methods available to me through active record when I open rails console. Will I be able to create a new category using `Product.create_category`?

Comment: honestly. It's better to create the belongs_to object first and have the has_many created second. So when you create a category you can associate or create a new product. but with products and categories I use a HABTM model. Not sure if it helps or not.